# Raspbian Stuck on Boot Info

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, boot, raspbian-stretch

I am new to the Raspberry Pi, so sorry if I am missing something obvious here. I was about to install something, so I typed in `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo-apt get upgrade` and then `sudo reboot`. While it was in the process of booting into the desktop (which is the default on my Pi), it was displaying the boot info (is that what the text appearing on the screen is called?) and for many of the items it said "failed". Then, it stopped scrolling through the text and showed a blinking cursor. I am unable to type anything in to the terminal, access it via SSH, or do anything like that at all. What can I do for it to boot to the desktop? Would it work to just unplug the Pi? I'd rather not do that though, if it's not necessary, or if it won't work. I read some similar questions which said that this may be due to an unreliable power supply, but I have a Raspberry Pi specific power supply that meets the voltage and current requirements. I have never had this issue in the few months that I have had my Pi. By the way, it's a Raspberry Pi 3B+ running Raspbian (Stretch, I'm pretty sure).

[image: the boot info screen that it is stuck on, but not quite frozen on since the cursor is blinking]

the boot info screen that it is stuck on, but not quite frozen on since the cursor is blinking

I would take a picture of my Pi, but its case kind of blocks the lights, so it wouldn't be helpful
Anyway, the red light is constantly on and the green is blinking.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question, and welcome.

Looks like a corrupted or failed SD card, there are a lot of filesystem errors in those boot messages. Reinstalling Raspbian on a new SD card should work.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Is there a way to transfer files from this SD to a new one?

Comment: Also, was there anything that may have led to the corruption of the SD card that I should avoid in the future? I know pulling the plug while the Pi is running can do this, but I have only done that a few times when absolutely necessary and it's been a while since I've had to do that. So is there anything else?

Comment: @user440774 It’s not necessarily anything you did. SD cards are pretty cheap. Best thing you can do is properly shutdown and backup anything important. Yes just put that SD card in another computer and copy over the files.